# My site show "We can't find products matching the selection" in category page

Tags: category, products, reindex, indexer, selection

I used the command

```
bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

and the product appeared. But then it disappeared again and showed the words `We can't find products matching the selection` on the category page.

Why is the error showing up after working once?

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code to view the table,

```
sql command select *
from catalog_eav_attribute cea 
join eav_attribute ea
  on ea.attribute_id = cea.attribute_id 
  and backend_type in ('text', 'varchar')
where 
  cea.is_filterable = 1
```

and Set is_filterable to 0 to allow category pages to load.

```
update catalog_eav_attribute cea 
join eav_attribute ea
  on ea.attribute_id = cea.attribute_id 
  and backend_type in ('text', 'varchar')
set cea.is_filterable = 0
where 
  cea.is_filterable = 1
```

then give the following

```
bin/magento indexer:reindex
bin/magento c:c
bin/magento c:f
```

Comment: is_filterable column has been set to 0 but it still not active

Comment: if i set it to 1 what happens?

Comment: Setting is_filterable to 1 for an attribute in Magento enables it as a filterable option on category pages, allowing customers to filter products based on that attribute. However, enabling too many filterable attributes can impact performance, increasing database query complexity and slowing down page loading times.

Answer (score 0):

Update **Elasticsearch Index Prefix**  from admin

like *magento_tung*

> Path : Admin -> Stores -> Configuration -> Catalog -> Catalog -> Catalog Search

Save the change and clear the cache

```
bin/magento indexer:reindex
bin/magento c:c
bin/magento c:f
```

Comment: thanks. i did it but still not working.

Comment: Please check index management is "Update by schedule" and check cron jobs working as well.